# Playing Card in Swift

Tags: swift, playing-cards

I'm trying to properly write a card class in swift. I've been taking classes in software engineering and I need help in understanding how to take a more object-oriented approach to my class. I have seen a Class for suit and rank and I'm wondering would that approach would be better? I have also seen the suit as enums and wonder if that approach would be better.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

```
class Card
```

```
private var rank: Int
private var suit: Int

init(n: Int) {
    self.rank = -1;
    self.suit = -1;
    if(n >= 0 && n <= 51) {
        self.rank = n % 13;
        self.suit = n / 13;
    }
}

func getRank() -> Int {
    return self.rank;
}

func getSuit() -> Int {
    return self.suit;
}

func compareRank(otherCard: Card) -> Bool {
    return self.rank == otherCard.getRank();
}

func compareSuit(otherCard: Card) -> Bool {
    return self.suit == otherCard.getSuit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Writing Style

1. In Swift, semicolons are not needed at the end of a line.
2. Specifying `self` in `self.suit` and `self.rank` is not needed (since there is no possible confusion). The compiler can infer that you are referring to the properties of this class.

---

### Initializer

With `rank` and `suit` defined as integers, a card would be initialized with `-1` as rank and suit if `n < 0`. As defined, the initializer would produce an invalid card. An honest initializer would fail instead :

```
init?(n: Int) {
    guard n >= 0 && n <= 51 else {
        return nil
    }
    rank = n % 13
    suit = n / 13
}
```

And since the suit and rank properties can't be changed (you've defined them as private properties with getter methods), it would be appropriate to define them as 
 constants:  `let` instead of `var`:

```
private let rank: Int
private let suit: Int
```

---

### Type Choices

1. Creating a card based on an integer isn't very intuitive. An alternative choice, as you've mentioned, would be using enums. Such an approach avoids the possibility of creating an invalid `Card` :

   ```
   enum Suit: Character {
       case spades = "♠", hearts = "♡", diamonds = "♢", clubs = "♣"
   }

   enum Rank: Int {
       case ace = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king
   }
   ```

Usually, it is not sufficient to look for equality when comparing the rank of a card. The value associated with a rank could be defined in a Blackjack game [this way](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/NestedTypes.html).

2. Using a struct instead of a class would be encouraged here since there is no flagrant purpose of having a shared mutable state for a Card instance. Plus, value types are stored in the Stack instead of the Heap, which allows quicker access.

---

Here is a version of your code with all the previous suggestions :

```
enum Suit: Character {
    case spades = "♠", hearts = "♡", diamonds = "♢", clubs = "♣"
}

enum Rank: Int {
    case ace = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king
}

class Card {

    private let rank: Rank
    private let suit: Suit

    init(_ rank: Rank, of suit: Suit) {
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    }

    func getRank() -> Rank {
        return rank
    }

    func getSuit() -> Suit {
        return suit
    }

    func compareRank(with otherCard: Card) -> Bool {
        return rank == otherCard.getRank()
    }

    func compareSuit(with otherCard: Card) -> Bool {
        return suit == otherCard.getSuit()
    }
}
```

And you could use it like so :

```
let a = Card(.ace, of: .spades)
let q = Card(.queen, of: .hearts)

print(a.getRank())              //ace
print(a.getSuit())              //spades
print(a.getSuit().rawValue)     //♠
print(q.getRank().rawValue)     //12
print(a.compareRank(with: q))   //false
print(a.compareSuit(with: q))   //false
```

Comment: while using self is not necessary I think it can make things more clear. Swift sacrifices a lot of readability for brevity.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Carpsen90 said:

#### No `get...` accessor methods

Unlike some other programming languages, you don't define accessor methods for the properties, these are implicitly created by the compiler. If `suit` and `rank` are constant properties (initialized once and never mutated) then it is simply

```
struct Card {
    let rank: Int
    let suit: Int

    // ...
}
```

For properties which are publicly read-only, but internally read-write, it is

```
 struct Card {
    private(set) var rank: Int
    private(set) var suit: Int

    // ...
}
```

That makes the `compareRank/Suit` methods obsolete, because you can directly  test

```
if card1.rank == card2.rank { ... }
```

etc.